# Creating and referring to underlying list items (list within a list within a list)

Tags: r, list

I would like to add 2 lists (1,2) to each list within a list and fill them with a for loop.

```
library(data.table)
library(mice)    
df <- fread(
    "A   B  C  D  E  F  iso   year   
     0   A   NA  1  NA  NA  NLD   2009   
     1   Y   NA  2  NA  NA  NLD   2009   
     0   Q   NA  3  NA  NA  AUS   2011   
     1   NA  NA  4  NA  NA  AUS   2011   
     0   0   NA  7  NA  NA  NLD   2008   
     1   1   NA  1  NA  NA  NLD   2008   
     0   1   NA  3  NA  NA  AUS   2012   
     0   NA  1   NA  1  NA  ECU   2009   
     1   NA  0   NA  2  0   ECU   2009   
     0   NA  0   NA  3  0   BRA   2011   
     1   NA  0   NA  4  0   BRA   2011   
     0   NA  1   NA  7  NA  ECU   2008   
     1   NA  0   NA  1  0   ECU   2008   
     0   NA  0   NA  3  2   BRA   2012   
     1   NA  0   NA  4  NA  BRA   2012",
   header = TRUE
)

# Creates a list
df_iso <- split(df, df$iso) # Creates a list of dataframes

# Creates a list of lists
mylist.names <- names(df_iso)
df_iso_list <- vector("list", length(mylist.names))
names(df_iso_list) <- mylist.names
```

Within `df_iso_list` I want to create two list for each `iso` code. So essentially, `df_iso_list` becomes a list with `iso`codes, which each have list numbers 1 and 2.

How do I create a list structure like this? And how do I refer to list 1 and 2?

Comment: I guess you want something like this? (but with `f` being a real function of each list element). `f <- function(x) return(list(a = 1, b = 2));
new_nested <- lapply(df_iso, f)`, and subset with e.g. `new_nested$AUS$a`

Comment: Thank you for you comment! The lists `1` and `2` somehow show up as type double, with the values 1 and 2 instead of being lists. Any way to fix that? I have tried to do `a=list()` and `b=list()`, but that does not work.

Comment: Wait it does work. Nevermind, thanks a lot!

Comment: One last thing.. If I would like to refer to `AUS` in `new_nested$AUS$a` by index, because I want to loop through the countries, something like `new_nested$[1]$a`, how would I do that?

Comment: I made a new question out of it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57920351/looping-through-a-sub-list-where-the-sub-sub-list-stays-constant