# Looping through a sub list, where the "sub sub" list stays constant

Tags: r, list, for-loop, lapply

I would like to loop through a sub list, where the "sub sub" list stays constant. All code mentioned by me is just the reproducible example (please note that the actual data is really large) and should work without issue.

I have a list of lists which each have 2 sub lists as follows:

```
library(data.table)  
library(mice)
df <- fread(
    "A   B  C  D  E  F  iso   year   
     0   A   NA  1  NA  NA  NLD   2009   
     1   Y   NA  2  NA  NA  NLD   2009   
     0   Q   NA  3  NA  NA  AUS   2011   
     1   NA  NA  4  NA  NA  AUS   2011   
     0   0   NA  7  NA  NA  NLD   2008   
     1   1   NA  1  NA  NA  NLD   2008   
     0   1   NA  3  NA  NA  AUS   2012   
     0   NA  1   NA  1  NA  ECU   2009   
     1   NA  0   NA  2  0   ECU   2009   
     0   NA  0   NA  3  0   BRA   2011   
     1   NA  0   NA  4  0   BRA   2011   
     0   NA  1   NA  7  NA  ECU   2008   
     1   NA  0   NA  1  0   ECU   2008   
     0   NA  0   NA  3  2   BRA   2012   
     1   NA  0   NA  4  NA  BRA   2012",
   header = TRUE
)

# Creates a list
df_iso <- split(df, df$iso) # Creates a list of dataframes

# Creates a list of lists
mylist.names <- names(df_iso)
df_iso_list <- vector("list", length(mylist.names))
names(df_iso_list) <- mylist.names

f <- function(x) return(list(a = list(), b = list()))
new_nested <- lapply(df_iso, f)
```

Now `new_nested$AUS$a` accesses the list `a` of sub list `AUS`. So far so good.

I would like to redistribute the two lists (`df_iso_1, df_iso_2`) below to the list structure I just created.

```
df_iso_1 = list()
for (i in 1:length(df_iso))  {
  tryCatch({
    df_iso_1 [[i]] <- mice(df_iso[[i]], m=1, maxit = 5, seed=1)
    if (i==1000) stop("stop")
  }, error=function(e){cat("ERROR :",conditionMessage(e), "\n")})
}

df_iso_2 = list()
for (i in 1:length(df_iso))  {
  tryCatch({
    df_iso_2 [[i]] <- mice(df_iso[[i]], m=1, maxit = 5, seed=2)
    if (i==1000) stop("stop")
  }, error=function(e){cat("ERROR :",conditionMessage(e), "\n")})
}
names(df_iso_1) <- names(df_iso)
names(df_iso_2) <- names(df_iso)
```

Although `new_nested$AUS$a` accesses the list, I would like to loop through the `iso` codes with an index instead of referring to them by name:

```
for (n in length(df_iso)) {
new_nested$[i]$a <- df_iso_1[n]
}
```

This does however not work. What is the correct syntax of looping through these lists?

Desired output:

From `df_iso_1` and `df_iso_2`, the `mids` objects are pooled per `iso` code. In other words, all `iso` codes are put together in the new structure:

So `new_nested` has its list `NLD` filled with the NLD `mids` objects from `df_iso_1` and `df_iso_2`, and its list list `AUS` filled with the AUS `mids` objects from `df_iso_1` and `df_iso_2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two approaches. The first is to fix your loop with `seq_len(length(df_iso))` and to match your output, changing your `df_iso_1[n]` to `df_iso1[[n]]`:

```
for (n in seq_len(length(df_iso))) {
  new_nested[[names(df_iso)[n]]]$a <- df_iso_1[[n]] 
  new_nested[[names(df_iso)[n]]]$b <- df_iso_2[[n]]
}

new_nested$AUS$a

Class: mids
Number of multiple imputations:  1 
Imputation methods:
   A    B    C    D    E    F  iso year 
  ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   "" 
PredictorMatrix:
  A B C D E F iso year
A 0 0 0 0 0 0   0    1
B 0 0 0 0 0 0   0    0
C 0 0 0 0 0 0   0    0
D 1 0 0 0 0 0   0    1
E 0 0 0 0 0 0   0    0
F 0 0 0 0 0 0   0    0
Number of logged events:  6 
  it im dep      meth out
1  0  0      constant   B
2  0  0      constant   C
3  0  0      constant   E
4  0  0      constant   F
5  0  0      constant iso
6  0  0     collinear   D
```

The second approach is to use `mapply` to loop through each element of your `df_iso_n` lists to combine them into a new matrix of lists:

```
mapply(list, df_iso_1, df_iso_2)

#     AUS     BRA     ECU     NLD    
#[1,] List,21 List,21 List,21 List,21
#[2,] List,21 List,21 List,21 List,21

mapply(list, df_iso_1, df_iso_2)[, 'AUS']

[[1]]
Class: mids
Number of multiple imputations:  1 
Imputation methods:
   A    B    C    D    E    F  iso year 
  ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   "" 
PredictorMatrix:
  A B C D E F iso year
A 0 0 0 0 0 0   0    1
B 0 0 0 0 0 0   0    0
C 0 0 0 0 0 0   0    0
D 1 0 0 0 0 0   0    1
E 0 0 0 0 0 0   0    0
F 0 0 0 0 0 0   0    0
Number of logged events:  6 
  it im dep      meth out
1  0  0      constant   B
2  0  0      constant   C
3  0  0      constant   E
4  0  0      constant   F
5  0  0      constant iso
6  0  0     collinear   D

[[2]]
Class: mids
Number of multiple imputations:  1 
Imputation methods:
   A    B    C    D    E    F  iso year 
  ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   "" 
PredictorMatrix:
  A B C D E F iso year
A 0 0 0 0 0 0   0    1
B 0 0 0 0 0 0   0    0
C 0 0 0 0 0 0   0    0
D 1 0 0 0 0 0   0    1
E 0 0 0 0 0 0   0    0
F 0 0 0 0 0 0   0    0
Number of logged events:  6 
  it im dep      meth out
1  0  0      constant   B
2  0  0      constant   C
3  0  0      constant   E
4  0  0      constant   F
5  0  0      constant iso
6  0  0     collinear   D
```

Also, it still would be a good idea to consider refactoring your code. This largely does everything in 3 lines:

```
seeds = c(1,2)

by(data = df, INDICES = df$iso,
   FUN = function(ISO) lapply(seeds, function(seed) mice(ISO, m = 1, maxit = 5, seed = seed)))

df$iso: AUS
[[1]]
Class: mids
Number of multiple imputations:  1 
Imputation methods:
   A    B    C    D    E    F  iso year 
  ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   "" 
PredictorMatrix:
  A B C D E F iso year
A 0 0 0 0 0 0   0    1
B 0 0 0 0 0 0   0    0
C 0 0 0 0 0 0   0    0
D 1 0 0 0 0 0   0    1
E 0 0 0 0 0 0   0    0
F 0 0 0 0 0 0   0    0
Number of logged events:  6 
  it im dep      meth out
1  0  0      constant   B
2  0  0      constant   C
3  0  0      constant   E
4  0  0      constant   F
5  0  0      constant iso
6  0  0     collinear   D

[[2]]
Class: mids
Number of multiple imputations:  1 
Imputation methods:
   A    B    C    D    E    F  iso year 
  ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   "" 
PredictorMatrix:
  A B C D E F iso year
A 0 0 0 0 0 0   0    1
B 0 0 0 0 0 0   0    0
C 0 0 0 0 0 0   0    0
D 1 0 0 0 0 0   0    1
E 0 0 0 0 0 0   0    0
F 0 0 0 0 0 0   0    0
Number of logged events:  6 
  it im dep      meth out
1  0  0      constant   B
2  0  0      constant   C
3  0  0      constant   E
4  0  0      constant   F
5  0  0      constant iso
6  0  0     collinear   D

---------------------------------------------------- 
df$iso: BRA
[[1]]
...
```

Comment: Thank you very much Cole! This is extremely helpful. I will use the last option if I ever need to rerun it. It takes almost three weeks to run however.

Comment: That's fair. Note that using ```by``` allows you to more easily use parallel computing. Using ```library(future.apply)``` and ```future_by```, I reduced the time from 200 ms to 140 ms with only a 2-core processor.